# How do i dynamically append url when onclick event occured?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

this is where i making a api call

```
export const filteredProducts = (e) => {
  const radio = e.target.checked;
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.TOGGLE_LOAD});
    axios.get(radio ? `/store?limit=9&skip=0&subcategory=${e.target.value}` : 
    `/store?limit=9&skip=0`)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setFilter(response.data, radio));
    })
  }
}
```

i wanted to do something like this. whenever i click on filter button the event has to appended to the existing url.

[image].

```
axios.get(`/store?limit=9&skip=0&subcategory=${e.target.value}&brand=${e.target.value}&{e.target.value}`)
```

I really do not know how to frame this question. If you want me to make it more clear I'll try to do that. since this is the client project i could not share the code base.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [URL and url.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API

```js
const url = new URL("/store?limit=9&skip=0");

const makeUrl = (name, value) => {
  if (name) {
    url.searchParams.append(name,value); // or searchParams.set to not append
  }
  return url;
};


export const filteredProducts = (e) => {
  const radio = e.target.checked;
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.TOGGLE_LOAD});
    axios.get(radio ? makeUrl(e.target.name, e.target.value) : makeUrl())
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setFilter(response.data, radio));
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot It really helped me. You are a saviour !. By the way how can remove it will slice method works

Comment: Ah, punctuation: _By the way, how can I remove it? Will the slice method work?_ Answer: _Don't use string manipulation. Use the API: [searchParams.delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete)_ or use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) instead of append